# Android studio Java Recycler view error on launch

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, runtime-error

I’m trying to learn how to code in Android studio, and I start with a Recycler view, unfortunately I have an error I don't know how to fixe it.

Thank you in advance for your help

Error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mtoapp, PID: 4393
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mtoapp/com.example.mtoapp.Recycler.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3450)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3602)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mtoapp.Recycler.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3602) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

MainActivity.java (all code)

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    String data1[], data2[];
    int images[];
    Context context;


    public MyAdapter(Context ct, String s1[], String s2[], int img[]){
    context = context;
    data1 = s1;
    data2 = s2;
    images = img;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row,parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.myText1.setText(data1[position]);
        holder.myText2.setText(data2[position]);
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView myText1, myText2;
        ImageView myImage;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myText1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myText1);
            myText2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myText2);
            myImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

        }
    }
}
```

Error part in the MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Find ID
---->   recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        //String S1 et S2
        s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days);
        s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);
```

External code who is link with :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.mtoapp.R;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    String data1[], data2[];
    int images[];
    Context context;


    public MyAdapter(Context ct, String s1[], String s2[], int img[]){
    context = context;
    data1 = s1;
    data2 = s2;
    images = img;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row,parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.myText1.setText(data1[position]);
        holder.myText2.setText(data2[position]);
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView myText1, myText2;
        ImageView myImage;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myText1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myText1);
            myText2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myText2);
            myImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you should initiate `recyclerview` like:

```java
RecyclerView recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_id);
```

then you can use `recyclerview.findViewById()`

Comment: Hello thank you for your help,

but I don't have R.id.recycler_view_id

Comment: add an `android:id="@+id/recycler_view_id"` attribute for your recyclerview in xml file then you have one =)

note: of course you can use other id than `recycler_view_id`

Comment: I follow a tutoriel on YouTube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18VcnYN5_LM

And the man didn't use a real recycler ... I don't know why but it's work for him and for the people in the chat ...

He used a ConstraintLayout -> CardView -> ConstraintLayout -> Img/text/...

Comment: you can find it in 04:23 of this video. he is adding an id to the recycler view and using that in the activity in 04:41

Comment: @ChangementDechaine open a new question for your other problem

Answer (score 0):

your error : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

this error 100% that your component not identified .
There is no problem with your adapter.
add athe following attribute to your RecyclerView in your xml like :

```
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
```

and then initiate it in activity and at last find it in onCreate